# Android XML Layout Auto Scale Unit?

Tags: android, layout, canvas, scale

I'm making a chart myself by drawing Canvas, which I can input the radius in XML like this:
[image]

The question is, on different screen size, my chart becomes smaller than expected. So is there any way to make the chart keep the same ratio on all screen?

Comment: You can use @dimen for both height and width to change based on screen size

Comment: Another option would be to set your custom View to match the parent's width and height, then have the View handle the scaling appropriately.

Comment: Hmm I think I should make multiple layout xml files. 
But that's too complicated to manage. 
Btw, what's the different to use @dimen and put straight 101.0dp as above, because I override the onMeasure to make the size of the view exactly double of radius1?